# Converting String to HTMLElement

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, gauge

I wish to draw a [canvas gauge](https://canvas-gauges.com/) by defining gauge components in HTML, but activating the drawing mechanism after the page has been drawn.

The [user documentation](https://canvas-gauges.com/documentation/user-guide/advanced-usage) says this can be achieved by doing the following

```
<script>window.GAUGES_NO_AUTO_INIT = true;</script>
<script src="../gauge.min.js"></script>
```

and defining the canvas gauge and then drawing it by using `BaseGauge.fromElement(canvasGaugeElement);`

I have a canvas element defined

```
<canvas class='canv' id='canv0' data-width=200 data-height=80 value=75 data-type='linear-gauge'></canvas>
```

I can successfully draw the gauge doing

```
BaseGauge.fromElement(canv0);
```

If I want to draw many canvas gauges at the same time, I could do

```
BaseGauge.fromElement(canv0);
BaseGauge.fromElement(canv1);
BaseGauge.fromElement(canv2);
```

However I thought to use the following code:

```
$('.canv').each(function(i, obj) {BaseGauge.fromElement($(this).attr('id'));});
```

However this fails because the BaseGauge.fromElement is expecting a HTMLElement and not a String

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Just try to replace `$(this).attr('id')` for `$(this)[0]` and I think it will work. You have the element and get the Id... just pass the element itself. Oh... or better just leave `this`... `$(this)[0]` is reduntant.

Comment: @ZeroWorks or even `BaseGauge.fromElement(this);`

Comment: @evolutionxbox yes... I realized myself and edited my comment... :)

Comment: Thanks! Your solutions both work.  If this is posted as a solution I will accept it!

Comment: @evolutionxbox, please post... ;)

Comment: @ZeroWorks, since no response.....so you post :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the id attribute of the object obtained in each loop... As `BaseGauge` requires an object you only have to pass the object itself:

```
$('.canv').each(function(i, obj) {BaseGauge.fromElement(this);});
```

And should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can do as follows:

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('canv').forEach((element) => BaseGauge.fromElement(element));
```

Comment: Consider also including a jQuery version since the question uses it?

Comment: Thanks very much @Ernesto Stifano.